# System.AccessViolationException при попытке использования Angle Sharp и CsQuery C# VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, anglesharp

Доброе день, вечер, утро, ночь.

Появилась задача спарсить с сайта определенные вещи. Но сейчас не про это.

**Язык**: C#.

**IDE**: VS 2012

**Инструменты для парсинга**: CsQuery или Angle Sharp. HtmlAgilityPack не хотелось бы использовать, ибо селекторы приятнее.

Подгружаю все NuGet'ом.

## Angle Sharp

Пытаюсь использовать AngleSharp. При создании любого объекта вылетает

```
 System.TypeInitializationException не обработано
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=Инициализатор типа "AngleSharp.Configuration" выдал исключение.
  Source=AngleSharp
  TypeName=AngleSharp.Configuration
  StackTrace:
       в AngleSharp.Configuration.get_Default()

       //вызовы моих функций

       в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       в System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       HResult=-2146233036
       Message=Инициализатор типа "AngleSharp.Factory" выдал исключение.
       Source=AngleSharp
       TypeName=AngleSharp.Factory
       StackTrace:
            в AngleSharp.Configuration..cctor()
       InnerException: System.AccessViolationException
            HResult=-2147467261
            Message=Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.
            InnerException:
```

Проанализировав понимаем, что вылетает ошибка то System.AccessViolationException(последние строчки), а AngleSharp реагирует на это и выдает свое.
P.S В git у них не нашел подобных жалоб.

## CsQuery

Тоже самое, но вылетает именно System.AccessViolationException

**Вывод**

Проблема на моей стороне. Но, как ее исправить, я не нашел.

**Вопрос:**

Как исправить и какая информация еще нужна?

P.S. Самое интересное:при попытке использовать HtmlAgiglityPack подобных проблем нет(тобишь проблема именно с этими пакетами). Юзаю также xNet, полет нормальный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не нашел решение проблемы на ноутбуке, но на PC все хорошо т.е проблема точно в ноутбуке. 
Если у вас возникла подобная проблема, попробуйте переустановить все(судя по всему нужно снести ОС).